# how to free memory malloced by called WTSEnumerateSessionsEx?

Tags: windows

now, i find my code have memory leak, but i search msdn about WTSEnumerateSessionsEx and WTSFreeMemoryEx function, but it leak also.

the following is code:

```
DWORD count = 0;
int ret = 0;
DWORD reserved = 1;
WTS_SESSION_INFO_1 *sinfo = NULL;
if (WTSEnumerateSessionsEx(handle_, &reserved, 0, &sinfo, &count)) {
    //......
    if (!WTSFreeMemoryEx(WTSTypeSessionInfoLevel1, sinfo, count))
    printf("free failure, error code is:%d\n", GetLastError());
}
```

execute the code, printf errorcode is 87,
how to free the system allocated WTS_SESSION_INFO_1 *sinfo ?

Comment: 87 is [invalid parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) - do you do anything to manipulate either `sinfo` or `count` inside `//.......`?

Comment: i don't change the sinfo and count value.

Comment: thank you answer, i have find the answer, my develop env is vs2008, i set character set is multi-byte set, so the WTS_SESSION_INFO_1 is WTS_SESSION_INFO_1A type, when i change to unicode set, the call of WTSFreeMemoryEx succeed.